# Scala, cats - how to create tagless-final implementation with IO (or other monad) and Either?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, tagless-final

I have created a simple `trait` and his implementation:

```
trait UserRepositoryAlg[F[_]] {

  def find(nick: String): F[User]

  def update(user: User): F[User]
}

class UserRepositoryInterpreter extends UserRepositoryAlg[Either[Error, *]] {
  override def find(nick: String): Either[Error, User] = for {
    res <- users.find(user => user.nick == nick).toRight(UserError)
  } yield res

  override def update(user: User): Either[Error, User] = for {
    found <- users.find(u => u.nick == user.nick).toRight(UserError)
    updated = found.copy(points = found.points + user.points)
  } yield updated
}
```

Here I would like to use `Either` or `EitherT` to "catch" errors, but I would like also to use `IO` or `Future` as a main monad. In my main class I created call to this implementation:

```
 object Main extends App {

  class Pointer[F[_] : Monad](repo: UserRepositoryAlg[F]) {
    def addPoints(nick: String): EitherT[F, Error, User] = {
      for {
        user <- EitherT.right(repo.find(nick))
        updated <- EitherT.right(repo.update(user))
      } yield Right(updated)
    }
  }
  val pointer = new Pointer[IO](new UserRepositoryInterpreter{}).addPoints("nick")
}
```

But in the line where `pointer` is created, IntelliJ shows me an error: `Type mismatch - required: UserRepositoryAlg[F], found: UserRepositoryInterpreter` and I do not understand why. I created `Pointer` class with `F[_]` as a `IO` and want to use the implementation of `UserRepositoryAlg[F]`. How I could fix this problem or what is a good practice in this case? If I want to achieve something like this: `IO[Either[Error, User]]` or `EitherT[IO, Error, User]`.

I tried to change `class UserRepositoryInterpreter extends UserRepositoryAlg[Either[Error, *]]` into something like `class UserRepositoryInterpreter[F[_]] extends UserRepositoryAlg[F[Either[Error, *]]]`, but it did not help me.

**EDIT:**
I found out how to return `F[Either[Error,User]]` by using `Applicative[F]` which transform `A => F[A]`:

```
class UserRepositoryInterpreter[F[_] : Applicative] extends UserRepositoryAlg[F[Either[Error, *]]] {
  override def find(nick: String): F[Either[Error, User]] = for {
    res <- Applicative[F].pure(users.find(user => user.nick == nick).toRight(UserError))
  } yield res

  override def update(user: User): F[Either[Error, User]] = for {
    found <- Applicative[F].pure(users.find(u => u.nick == user.nick).toRight(UserError))
    updated = Applicative[F].pure(found.map(u => u.copy(points = u.points + user.points)))
  } yield updated
}
```

But I still have a problem in the main function, because I cannot get `Right` value of `Either`:

```
 def addPoints(nick: String): EitherT[F, Error, User] = {
      for {
        user <- EitherT.liftF(repo.find(nick))
        updated <- EitherT.rightT(repo.update(user))
      } yield Right(updated)
    }
```

Here `updated <- EitherT.rightT(repo.update(user))` `user` is `Either[Error, User]`, but I need to pass only `User`. So I tried to do something like:
`Right(user).map(u=>u)` and pass it but it also does not help. How I should take this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`F[_]` describes your main effect. In theory, you could use any monad(or even any higher-kinded-type), but in practice, the best choice is a monad, that allows you to suspend execution like `cats-effect` or `Future`.

Your problem is that you're trying to use `IO` as your main effect, but for `UserRepositoryInterpreter` your set `Either` as your `F`.

What you should do is just parametrize `UserRepositoryInterpreter`, that you could choose your effect monad. If you want to use both `Either` for handling errors and `F` for suspending effects, you should use monad stack `F[Either[Error, User]]`.

Example solution:

```
import cats.Monad
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.effect.{IO, Sync}
import cats.implicits._

case class User(nick: String, points: Int)

trait UserRepositoryAlg[F[_]] {

  def find(nick: String): F[Either[Error, User]]

  def update(user: User): F[Either[Error, User]]
}

//UserRepositoryInterpreter is parametrized, but we require that F has typeclass Sync,
//which would allow us to delay effects with `Sync[F].delay`.
//Sync extends Monad, so we don't need to request is explicitly to be able to use for-comprehension
class UserRepositoryInterpreter[F[_]: Sync] extends UserRepositoryAlg[F] {

  val users: mutable.ListBuffer[User] = ListBuffer()

  override def find(nick: String): F[Either[Error, User]] = for {
    //Finding user will be delayed, until we interpret and run our program. Delaying execution is useful for side-effecting effects,
    //like requesting data from database, writting to console etc.
    res <- Sync[F].delay(Either.fromOption(users.find(user => user.nick == nick), new Error("Couldn't find user")))
  } yield res


  //we can reuse find method from UserRepositoryInterpreter, but we have to wrap find in EitherT to access returned user
  override def update(user: User): F[Either[Error, User]] = (for {
    found <- EitherT(find(user.nick))
    updated = found.copy(points = found.points + user.points)
  } yield updated).value
}

object Main extends App {

  class Pointer[F[_] : Monad](repo: UserRepositoryAlg[F]) {
    def addPoints(nick: String): EitherT[F, Error, User] = {
      for {
        user <- EitherT(repo.find(nick))
        updated <- EitherT(repo.update(user))
      } yield updated
    }
  }

  //at this point we define, that we want to use IO as our effect monad
  val pointer = new Pointer[IO](new UserRepositoryInterpreter[IO]).addPoints("nick")

  pointer.value.unsafeRunSync() //at the end of the world we run our program

}
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks interesting I will analyze it. Also Do you think, it is a good practise to do something like `F[Either[Error, Data]]` or it should be rewrite into something else?

Comment: It's a very common practice. Actually `EitherT` is a monad transformer used to simplify operation on such nested monads. If you use effect monad there's also another way of handling errors. You could use [raiseError](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/io.html#raiseerror) from `MonadError` typeclass. In this case you don't need to nest monads (so your type would be for example just `F[User]`).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any syntax sugar for `Sync[F].delay(...)`? By using it as implicits or something else?

Comment: You could, for example, define `UserRepositoryInterpreter` as `class UserRepositoryInterpreter[F[_]](implicit S: Sync[F])` (sometimes implicit parameters are defined with uppercase when they describe typeclasses, you could also use lowercased `s` or `sync`) and then use it like `S.delay`. But actually notation `Sync[F].delay` is very common. Please check out this [cats effect tutorial](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/tutorial/tutorial.html). Actually resolving implicit with the notation `Sync[F]` is called using *implicit summoner*, and it looks kinda weird at first I admit :)

Comment: Thanks for help. Will look at this tutorial.